# Postfix 451, 4.3.0 : Temporary lookup failure

Tags: postfix, smtp

we've followed the guide [HERE](https://www.tecmint.com/install-postfix-mail-server-with-webmail-in-debian/) to configure a Postfix. After sending a message via telnet we receive the following error:

```
Oct  8 18:52:01 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: connect from unknown[10.10.10.9]
Oct  8 18:52:01 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: warning: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: non-null host address bits in "10.10.10.5/22", perhaps you should use "10.10.8.0/22" instead
Oct  8 18:52:02 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: warning: mynetworks: non-null host address bits in "10.10.10.5/22", perhaps you should use "10.10.8.0/22" instead
Oct  8 18:52:02 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[10.10.10.9]: 451 4.3.0 <admin@acme.org>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<ArchivematicaSystem@archivematica.org> to=<admin@acme.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<UBUNTUSRV-16-ARCHIVEMATICA>
Oct  8 18:52:02 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: warning: smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions: non-null host address bits in "10.10.10.5/22", perhaps you should use "10.10.8.0/22" instead
Oct  8 18:52:02 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: lost connection after RSET from unknown[10.10.10.9]
Oct  8 18:52:02 mail postfix/smtpd[3719]: disconnect from unknown[10.10.10.9] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 rset=1 commands=4/5
```

Following the main.cf content:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.myDomain.com
mydomain = myDomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.10.10.5/22
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
#inet_protocols = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
# SMTP-Auth settings
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Simone

Comment: non-null host address bits in "10.10.10.5/22"
your ip/netmask looks wrong.

Comment: @Dennis Nolte that is the static IP assigned to the host

Comment: I've also added the ip from which I am trying to send the email. From the local smtp the sending is ok, from outside it's not working

Comment: what ip should be allowed?
10.10.10.5 or the network 10.10.10.4/22?
cause the network 10.10.10.5/22 still looks wrong/invalid.
http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=A
see the documentation here>
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html
examples:
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 168.100.189.0/28
mynetworks = !192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.0/28
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 168.100.189.0/28 [::1]/128 [2001:240:587::]/64
looks like you should give it a netmask, not an IP if you give the subnetbits.
This is exactly the message the logs give you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've enabled the whole subnet segment by setting the *0/24 in the 'mynetworks' parameters as reference to the host which is using the smtp.

Comment: change from: [XXX:ZZZ:EEE:999]/56 to [XXX:ZZZ:EEE:999::]/56 solve my issue thx ::

Answer (score 2):

```
#grep -w mynetworks /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep -v "#"
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128, 10.10.8.0/22
```

Change the 10.10.10.5/22 value to 10.10.8.0/22 or 10.10.10.0/24, if it is required to allow send emails from whole subnet segment.
example outside subnet XXX.XXX.125.0/24 
outside any segment  [::1]/128 listen-on-v6

Restart postfix:

```
service postfix restart
```